# Using LuaTex / LuaLaTeX with Latexian on Mac

Tags: luatex, mactex, latexian

I've been using Latexian for a while. Its LivePreview feature is very convenient, which is why I'm keeping using it.

Recently, I've heard about LuaTeX / LuaLaTeX. I tried a couple of examples but I couldn't make it work with Latexian.

Specifically, compiling the following code via terminal "lualatex test.tex" works ok.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
The standard approximation $\pi = \directlua{tex.sprint(math.pi)}$
\end{document}
```

As expected, this doesn't compile in Latexian since it uses "pdflatex".

I tried to delete "pdflatex" file in /usr/texbin and create a symbolic link named "pdflatex" pointing to "lualatex" to trick Latexian, but it didn't work. I get the following error:

```
 This is LuaTeX, Version beta-0.76.0-2013061817 (rev 4627) 
 \write18 enabled.

---! pdflatex.fmt was written by pdftex
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

Even in terminal, trying to compile with "pdflatex" (now pointing to "lualatex") doesn't work. Same error as above.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you be a _bit_ more specific? What did you try, what didn't work?

Comment: Ok, I edited the question adding more information. Thanks.

Comment: The error message is seriously confusing: LuaTeX asks for `pdflatex.fmt`?

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I got it.

LuaTeX calls, at some time, pdflatex. If pdflatex is pointing to luatex, then we get an infinite recursion.

Instead, I replaced pdflatex with the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
PARENT_COMMAND=$(ps $PPID | tail -n 1 | awk "{print \$5}")
#echo $PARENT_COMMAND
if [ $PARENT_COMMAND == '/Applications/Latexian.app/Contents/MacOS/Latexian' ]; then
        lualatex "$@"
else
        pdftex "$@"
fi
```

It identifies who's calling pdflatex. Then, if Latexian calls pdflatex, it is redirected to lualatex. Else, it calls pdftex, to which pdflatex pointed before the modification.